# VB.net - how to split a string using " followed by a space as a delimiter

Tags: vb.net, split, space, double-quotes

I have an string that is returned from an xml file and looks similar to this

```
name1="test 1" name2="test2" name3="test 3"
```

I want to split this into 3 elements of key=value. I can't just split using a space because some of my values may contain spaces, e.g., test 1.

So, I'd like to split the string using the " before the space. I've tried many variations but can't figure out the correct syntax to specify that my split characters are a " followed by a space. For instance, I've tried `text.split({""" "})` but that returns elements split by " and ignores the space after the ".

It shouldn't be this difficult. Can someone please help me with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
text.Split(New String() {""" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

**Update**

Since this will remove the trailing " in all but the last element, you need to account for this when processing the results.

Here is an example:

```
    Dim sValue As String = "name1=""test 1"" name2=""test2"" name3=""test 3"""

    Dim asValues As String() = sValue.Split(New String() {""" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For Each sKVP As String In asValues
        If Not sKVP.EndsWith("""") Then
            sKVP &= """"
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(sKVP)
    Next
```

and the resultant output:

```
name1="test 1"
name2="test2"
name3="test 3"
```

Comment: I got the same result trying this.

Comment: @user1144318: You have to account for the trailing " that is stripped. I have updated the answer to show this and the test results.

Comment: Your example has quotes in places my text string doesn't. But I ended up rewriting my code to use XMLDocument and now I'm retrieving the parameter values using methods available through that class. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: @user1144318: That is just VB syntax to get to the exact string that you have in your question. Can you edit the question and show the exact string that you are using?

Comment: The exact string was in my first post above.

Comment: Right, that string value that I have is exactly the same as the one in your original question. The quotes are doubled-up in the middle because that's what VB requires to output a single double-quote. This is the output of that string (i.e. what VB uses at runtime): `name1="test 1" name2="test2" name3="test 3"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to create the `Dictionary(Of String, String)`:

```
Dim q = From item In value.Split({""" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Select item.Split("="c)

Dim dict = q.ToDictionary(Function(i) (i(0)),
                          Function(i) (i(1)))
```

<sub>**Note**: this is not fail-safe, f.e. if there are repeating keys, you'll get an exception.</sub>

Comment: But this doesn't address the problem with not getting the right elements returned by the split in the first place. The split itself is returning elements using just the ", not the combination of 2 characters " plus a following space.